# unity3d scroll bar horizontal doesn't work

Tags: scroll, alignment, unity-game-engine

I have a panel with list of gameobjects and scroll bar. Some times ago I have make it with vertical scrolling. But now when I want to horizontal align and scroll, it doesn't work.

Have anyone ideas why it can be?

Answer (score 0):

to make a horizontal scrollbar check this 
[Horizontal scrollbar](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.HorizontalScrollbar.html)
You use 
GUI.HorizontalScrollbar
instead of verticalScrollbar